# Angular-Highcharts: Quickly redraw chart after changing plotOptions

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

This question is specific to angular-highcharts and not highcharts-angular.

I have a plotOption that I want the user to be able to toggle on/off. We want to redraw the chart as efficiently as possible after the user switches the toggle. I have a working solution that redraws the chart by passing in the series data and all the original options, but it seems like there should be a better way.

This seems like it should be an easy question, but I have yet to find the answer after looking at the limited documentation found at https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-highcharts.

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue in an online code editor like codesandbox? Why don't you want to use official `highcharts-angular` wrapper?

Comment: I'm working with an existing codebase, so I don't have that option.

Comment: Try to use sample data and prepare just a simplified example of this issue. Have you tried using `chart.redraw()` method (see: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#redraw)?